# pass statusCode to error middleware with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

A middleware with 4 params in Express is fired when an error occurs. Based on this, I would like to keep a super simple structure to fire errors based on the statusCode.

In my `middleware.js` file, I do this:

```
models.pool.query(
      "SELECT * FROM user,function(err, query) {
            if(err) { err.statusCode = 500; return next(err) }
```

And I've placed the error middleware at the end of my initial script file `app.js`. The middleware is launched but err.statusCode is totally empty, so it doesnt work:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;  //--> err.statusCode is empty!!
    if(env != 'test') log.error(err);
    if(statusCode == 500) err.message = 'Internal server error';
    if(statusCode == 404) err.message = 'Not found';
    res.status(err.statusCode).send(err);
});
```

Any ideas about what is going on? thanks!!

Comment: Where do you define `middleware.js`? And how it looks?

Comment: In a separated directory called 'middleware'. I call it in `app.js` with `var middleware = require('./middleware')`. They're called at function level: `app.post('/api/auth',  middleware.authenticate, function(...`
The middleware are executed fine, and the error middleware is always launched when must be done.

Comment: Add that middleware in question.